# How can I update the value I draw with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to do an android app that gets and displays the battery percentage, but I can't get it to update.

I tried using the function `updateBatteryPct` but because it has a delay (else it crashes) it is registered as suspend it cannot be used in `onCreate` because making `onCreate` suspend causes it to not be an override anymore.
This is one of my many tries to update this value, I am not even sure that `updateBatteryPct` will even work. I would appreciate if someone could explain me in depth how this works bc I dont understad really everything. I can code in Kotlin and do stuff but I can't do anything that works for android.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    var batteryStatus: Intent? = null
    var batteryPct: MutableState<Int> = mutableStateOf(0)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(/* savedInstanceState = */ savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            this.batteryStatus = getBatteryStatusReceiver()
            this.batteryPct = remember {
                mutableStateOf(0)
            }
            BatterySaverAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    getBatteryPct(this.batteryStatus, this.batteryPct)
                    DisplayBatteryPercentage(batteryPercentage = this.batteryPct)
                }
            }
        }
        }
        suspend fun updateBatteryPct () {
            while (true) {
                getBatteryPct(this.batteryStatus, this.batteryPct)
                delay(1000)
                Log.d("customTest", "updateBatteryPct: Looping")
            }
        }
    }

    class BatteryManagerBroadcastReceiver(
        private val onReceiveIntent: (Intent) -> Unit,
    ) : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            onReceiveIntent(intent)
        }
    }
    @Composable
    fun updateBatteryPct(batteryStatus: Intent?, batteryPct: MutableState<Int>) {
        while (true) {
            getBatteryPct(batteryStatus, batteryPct)
            DisplayBatteryPercentage(batteryPercentage = batteryPct)
        }
    }


    fun getBatteryPct(batteryStatus: Intent?, batteryPct: MutableState<Int>){
        batteryPct.value =  batteryStatus?.let { intent ->
            val level: Int = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1)
            val scale: Int = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1)
            level * 100 / scale
        }!!
    }

    @Composable
    fun getBatteryStatusReceiver(): Intent? {
        val batteryStatus: Intent? = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED).let { ifilter ->
            LocalContext.current.applicationContext.registerReceiver(null, ifilter)
        }
        return batteryStatus
    }

    @Composable
    fun DisplayBatteryPercentage(batteryPercentage: MutableState<Int>) {
        Column(Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
            Text("battery is at ${batteryPercentage.value}%") }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to register the `BroadcastReceiver` with a side effect.

Something like:

```
@Composable
fun SystemBroadcastReceiver(
    systemAction: String,
    onSystemEvent: (intent: Intent?) -> Unit
) {
    // Grab the current context in this part of the UI tree
    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Safely use the latest onSystemEvent lambda passed to the function
    val currentOnSystemEvent by rememberUpdatedState(onSystemEvent)

    // If either context or systemAction changes, unregister and register again
    DisposableEffect(context, systemAction) {
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter(systemAction)
        val broadcast = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                currentOnSystemEvent(intent)
            }
        }

        context.registerReceiver(broadcast, intentFilter)

        // When the effect leaves the Composition, remove the callback
        onDispose {
            context.unregisterReceiver(broadcast)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your composable just update the value:

```
var battery by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

SystemBroadcastReceiver(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED) { batteryStatus ->
    val batteryPct: Float? = batteryStatus?.let { intent ->
        val level: Int = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1)
        val scale: Int = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1)
        level * 100 / scale.toFloat()
    }
    battery = batteryPct!!.toInt()
}
```